# Manage the edit users in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a database of users, and I want that only the current user is able to modify his own page.

My routes are very simple:

```
resources :users
```

And in my users_controller I have an edit function. My current problem is that, if you are user 1, you can access `users/1/edit` which is good, but you can also access `users/2/edit`, and then be able to modify another user.

What is the best way to avoid this problem ?

Currently, I tried to put this code in the users_controller, but with this, even the current user cannot modify his own page :(

```
before_action :require_permission, only: :edit

def require_permission
 if current_user.id != params[:id]
  flash['alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'] = "Vous n'avez pas accès à cette page"
  redirect_to users_path
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, make link for `users/:id/edit` available only if `current_user` id equal to `id` from `users/:id/edit`. Something like, this should be in views:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if current_user && (user.id == current_user.id) %>
      <%= link_to 'edit', edit_user_path(user) %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to 'edit', '#' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Also check privileges in the controller action for edit user.

```
def edit
  if current_user && (current_user.id == params[:id])
    # do the stuff
    # ....
  else
    redirect_to :some_action
```

For reuse this code you can make `before_action` for check user privileges in every action that you need.

In `application_controller.rb` write a method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # some code here

  def check_priveleges
    unless current_user && (current_user.id == params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  # some code here
end
```

In `users_controller.rb` write a `before_action`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # some code here
  before_action :check_priveleges, only: [:edit]
  # this mean pass to the `edit` action only after :check_priveleges filter

  def edit
    # already pass through :check_privilege action in `ApplicationController`
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But, precisely how do I write that it is only available if current_user.id == :id ? Sorry, I am really new to rails

Comment: Thanks for the update. My problem is that I can still change the url in the browser, and access the page. How do you set up the check priviledges in the controller ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, is it possible to DRY this code ? (if I need to check several times in the same controller that the current user is the one in the url ?)

Comment: @saraf yep, check update, but be careful it's can contain very furry bugs.

Comment: Great thanks a lot !!!!! I noticed that it was working only if I was testing current_user.id.to_i != params[:id].to_i however

Answer (score 2):

You can use available ***authorization gems*** like `pundit`,`cancancan` etc. Here is an example using with `pundit`.

***Sample code***

```
#app/policies/user_policy.rb
class UserPolicy
  attr_reader :current_user

  def initialize(current_user)
    @current_user = current_user
  end

  def edit?
    @current_user
  end
end

#users_controller
def edit
  @user = current_user
  authorize @user
end
```

Comment: use `cancancan` instead `cancan`. The old `cancan` gem not compatible with Rails 4

Comment: good but at first time in Rails programming hard to understand. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers !